# How to get Alfresco node knowing its text string representation of a node ref?

Tags: alfresco

I have a string representation of Alfresco node, saying "workspace://SpacesStore/1ed7e740-9d01-4b5a-8a63-8284094e6c71" and need a NodeRef object from it.

```
 NodeRef connectedDocument = new NodeRef(s);
 nodeService.getProperty(connectedDocument, NDBaseDocumentModel.PROP_MARK)
```

When I trying to get its property I got error:

```
org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.InvalidNodeRefException: Node does not exist: "workspace://SpacesStore/1ed7e740-9d01-4b5a-8a63-8284094e6c71" (status:null),
org.alfresco.repo.node.db.DbNodeServiceImpl.getNodePairNotNull(DbNodeServiceImpl.java:198),

org.alfresco.repo.node.db.DbNodeServiceImpl.hasAspect_aroundBody38(DbNodeServiceImpl.java:1043), 
org.alfresco.repo.node.db.DbNodeServiceImpl$AjcClosure39.run(DbNodeServiceImpl.java:1), 
org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.JoinPointImpl.proceed(JoinPointImpl.java:149), 
org.alfresco.traitextender.RouteExtensions.intercept(RouteExtensions.java:100), 
org.alfresco.repo.node.db.DbNodeServiceImpl.hasAspect(DbNodeServiceImpl.java:1037), 
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor284.invoke(Unknown Source), 
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43), 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498), 
org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317),
```

and when I tried "solr-alfresco" search I got an exception:

```
org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.lucene.LuceneQueryParserException: 11170021 Request failed 400
```

Please tell me, how to get a node knowing its string representation?

Comment: Give us a context, when are where are you trying to do this?

Comment: You are asking two different questions. The first error is saying that the node that you are trying to read does not exist. How are you getting that noderef ? Is it possible that it is the noderef of a node creating in a different transaction?

We can help with the error on the search if you give us more details. What have you tried? There seems to be an error in the syntax of the query.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code to Get all properties from the node or a single property from the node.

```
String nodeId = request.getParamater("nodeId"); //You can get the param from request for example

if (StringUtils.isNumeric(nodeId)) {
        final NodeRef nodeReference = AuthenticationUtil.runAs(new AuthenticationUtil.RunAsWork<NodeRef>() {
            @Override
            public NodeRef doWork() {
                return nodeService.getNodeRef(Long.valueOf(nodeId));
            }
        }, AuthenticationUtil.getSystemUserName());
                
        if (nodeReference !=null){
//Get all properties from the node
            final Map<QName, Serializable> properties = nodeService.getProperties(nodeReference); 
            
//OR

//Get A property from the node. Example: ContentModel.PROP_TITLE
final QName aProp = nodeService.getProperty(nodeReference, propQName); 


//OR

nodeService.setProperty(actionedUponNodeRef, propQName, "A value");

        }
}
```

**Update :**

```
getNodeFromString
public ScriptNode getNodeFromString(String nodeRefString)
Gets a JS node object from a string noderef
Parameters:
nodeRefString - string reference to a node
Returns:
a JS node object
```

**UPDATE :**
https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-repository/blob/master/src/main/java/org/alfresco/repo/jscript/ScriptUtils.java

```
 * Gets a JS node object from a string noderef
 * 
 * @param nodeRefString     string reference to a node
 * @return                  a JS node object
 */
public ScriptNode getNodeFromString(String nodeRefString)
{
    NodeRef nodeRef = new NodeRef(nodeRefString);
    return (ScriptNode)new ValueConverter().convertValueForScript(this.services, getScope(), null, nodeRef);
}
```

Comment: How can I get the nodeId form "workspace://SpacesStore/1ed7e740-9d01-4b5a-8a63-8284094e6c71" ?

Comment: getNodeFromString(noderef) returns a ScriptNode object representing the supplied NodeRef string.

Comment: Sorry I did not understood how did you got node id.

Comment: Please see my latest update in old answer, there is api available to get the nodeId from the node string.

Comment: What is ScriptNode and why do I need it? As I understand I need a Long type nodeId, and I have no such parameter. I just have a string representation of node (see above). Please tell me more details?